# Can I2P sites run Javascript?

Tags: javascript, i2p

(There's a few I2P questions on this Stackexchange so I hope this is allowed)

I know there's a lot of concern about running Javascript on Onion sites, but I'm wondering is it possible at all to run an Eepsite with Javascript enabled?

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing inherently bad about javascript on tor or i2p, but there is a concern about using badly written javascript.

If you're using good code that doesn't 1. give away your personal information and 2. doesn't try to steal your visitor's personal information, then there's nothing wrong with it.

If you're not a web developer and you want to use some random javascript from the web that you don't know what it does, then it is suggested that you use caution because it might not do what you expect.

IMHO, javascript should be like adding salt to your food. A little is OK but too much is disgusting. If your site isn't functional without javascript, it's too much. Expect people to be visiting with javascript turned off. If that means that they can't use your site, then you should consider not having so much.

Comment: The big concern about Javascript is that it's a major source of security holes in web browsers.  If an attacker can run arbitrary code on your system, it's not a problem to bypass the anonymity of either Tor or I2P.